# How to fix submit button only working in certain cases with react-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hook-form

I'm currently working on a next.js and react.js website which uses Firestore to store data. I've recently created an admin page where you can create a post then edit and preview it. In the edit form you can change the context as well as the publish status. Except the issue i'm getting is I can only click the submit button and run the postForm function when the published checkbox is checked. When I go in preview mode without the checked published box the content edits are there but when i click submit, the database doesn't update.

Any ideas?

This is the code :

Imports :

```
import styles from '../../styles/Admin.module.css';
import AuthCheck from '../../components/AuthCheck';
import { firestore, auth } from '../../lib/firebase';
import { serverTimestamp, doc, collection, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import { useDocumentData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import Link from 'next/link';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';
```

This is where the page components are posted :

```
export default function AdminPostEdit(props) {
  return (
    <AuthCheck>
      <PostManager />
    </AuthCheck>
  );
}
```

This is the general view where you can see the created post :

```
function PostManager(){
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(false);

  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug } = router.query;

  const postRef = doc(collection(firestore, 'posts'), slug)
  const [post] = useDocumentData(postRef);

  return (
    <main className={styles.container}>
      {post && (
        <>
          <section>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <p>ID: {post.slug}</p>

            <PostForm postRef={postRef} defaultValues={post} preview={preview} />
          </section>

          <aside>
          <h3>Tools</h3>
            <button onClick={() => setPreview(!preview)}>{preview ? 'Edit' : 'Preview'}</button>
            <Link href={`/${post.username}/${post.slug}`} legacyBehavior>
              <button className="btn-blue">Live view</button>
            </Link>
          </aside>
        </>
      )}
    </main>
  );
}
```

This is the form to edit the post where I believe I'm getting my issue :

```
function PostForm({ defaultValues, postRef, preview }) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, watch } = useForm({ defaultValues, mode: 'onChange' });

  const updatePost = async ({ content, published }) => {
    console.log('Update post:', content, published);
    await updateDoc(postRef,{
      content,
      published,
      updatedAt: serverTimestamp(),
    });
    console.log('Post updated successfully');
    reset({ content, published });

    toast.success('Post updated successfully!')
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(updatePost)}>
      {preview && (
        <div className="card">
          <ReactMarkdown>{watch('content')}</ReactMarkdown>
        </div>
      )}

      <div className={preview ? styles.hidden : styles.controls}>
  
        <textarea name="content" {...register('content', { required: true })}></textarea>

        <fieldset>
          <input className={styles.checkbox} name="published" {...register('published', { required: true })} type="checkbox" />
          <label>Published</label>
        </fieldset>

        <button type="submit" className="btn-green">
          Save Changes
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your `published` field could be holding you back here as it is required field you can remove `{ required: true }` from published field and set published field in `updateDoc` as `published: published || false`. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: @RohitKharche What you told me worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was given by @RohitKharche fixed my issue.

Here is is for anyone wondering :

> Your published field could be holding you back here as it is required
> field you can remove { required: true } from published field and set
> published field in updateDoc as published: published || false. Let me
> know if it worked.